# In an array object how to change only value on second level

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, javascript-objects

I have an array object i want to change the value of isFavorite to true only in second level (where name is pear) i tried map function but that is changing value on every level and i have written that function below can anyone look what is wrong with it?

Function

```js
const fruitChecked = fruits.map((fruit) => ({
  ...fruit,
  attributes: fruit[1].attributes.map((attribute) => ({
    ...attribute,
    isFavorite: true,
  })),
}));
```

Array Example

```js
[
  {
    name: "apple",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Granny Smith", color: "green", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "Ambrosia", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Persian", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "greek", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Pear",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "White Pear", color: "white", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "White Pear", color: "white", isFavorite: false },
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried the function which i mentioned in question and also mentioned the dat with which i am trying. and i used map but that is not giving me the result``

Comment: Terminology correction: you have an array, not an array object. (although you _do_ have an array _of_ objects).

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing.  Currently the code has syntax errors, and fails with an exception after correcting those.

Comment: You have: `attributes: fruit[1].attributes.map(...)` - should be `attributes: fruit.attributes.map(...)`

Comment: @James even if i use fruit.attributes.map(...) it is changing the value for both objects i want to change only second object

Comment: @JavascriptLearner: If you only want to change one element of an array, don't loop over the array.  Just change that one element.  The code shown has *two* (nested) loops (well, calls to `.map()`).  Maybe you meant to have *one* call to `.map()` on *only* the data you want to change?

Comment: @JavascriptLearner i tried but in that case that value is not updated in the nested array object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are after?

```js
const fruits=[
      {name: 'apple', 
       attributes: [
          {type: 'Granny Smith', color:'green', isFavorite: true},
          {type: 'Ambrosia', color:'red', isFavorite: false},
          {type: 'Persian', color:'red', isFavorite: false},
          {type: 'Asian', color:'brown', isFavorite: true},
          {type: 'greek', color:'red', isFavorite: false}
       ], 
 
    },
   {name: 'Pear', 
    attributes: [
      {type: 'Asian', color:'brown', isFavorite: true},
      {type: 'White Pear', color:'white', isFavorite: false},
      {type: 'Asian', color:'brown', isFavorite: true},
      {type: 'White Pear', color:'white', isFavorite: false}
    ], 
   }
  ];
 
fruits[1].attributes.forEach(a=>a.isFavorite=true);

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the map, you need to check if the fruit name is Pear before changing the attributes:

```js
const fruits = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Granny Smith", color: "green", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "Ambrosia", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Persian", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "greek", color: "red", isFavorite: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Pear",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "White Pear", color: "white", isFavorite: false },
      { type: "Asian", color: "brown", isFavorite: true },
      { type: "White Pear", color: "white", isFavorite: false },
    ],
  },
];

const adjustedFruits = fruits.map(fruit => ({
  ...fruit,
  attributes: fruit.name === "Pear"
    ? fruit.attributes.map(att => ({
      ...att,
      isFavorite: true
    }))
    : fruit.attributes
}));

console.log(adjustedFruits);
```

Comment: It is used when i want to change all attributes value what if i only want to change only 1 value or two value?

Comment: Similarly to how `attributes` is set with a ternary, you could do a similar thing when setting `isFavorite` if you wanted to check type for example.